# Keep white space when pasting into a .h file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am charged with maintaining a .h file. The formatting includes preserving white spaces (spaces, not tabs) between columns of colors.

When I copy and paste a previous line, all the spaces are collapsed, and I have to manually put them back in.

Is there a setting I can flip to keep the white spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll probably want to turn off the auto formatting when pasting: `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Automatically format when I paste`

There's some other auto formatting settings there you might want to modify also, including customizing how auto formatting is performed.

If you want Tab to insert spaces instead of tabs change `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Tabs->Insert Spaces`

Comment: Thanks! Your first item did the trick. The tab/spaces issue I have already set to accommodate the tabs that are required in different files.

Comment: You can also hit "undo" (Ctrl-Z on Windows) after pasting, if you don't want to permanently change this setting.